# Results that are easier in a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, uniform-spaces

Are there any significant results in the theory of metric spaces that (are considerably more difficult to reproduce/have not been reproduced) in the theory of uniform spaces?

In particular, I'm interested in any results relating to analysis that might be manifest when viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as a metric space but would be less visible when viewing $\mathbb{R}$ as a uniform space. I'm attempting to define integration in a setting more general than but similar to $\mathbb{R}$, and I'm wondering if I should bother defining a 'nonstandard metric' and exploring that point of view or if I should feel comfortable moving to a uniform point of view that would be induced by such a metric immediately.

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/212308/baire-category-theorem-for-complete-uniform-spaces (the Baire category theorem *does not hold* in complete uniform spaces — I'm not sure if you count this as being "easier" in a metric space, but it seems worth mentioning).

Comment: @Gro-Tsen This is relevant to my interests -- I suspect that some counterexamples can be found in the very large, very dense non-Archimedean real closed fields. These are uniform spaces under the canonical entourages induced by their nonstandard metrics, but the fields can get so dense that I suspect they admit countable collections of disjoint dense open subsets.

Comment: Urysohn's Lemma becomes a lot easier in metric spaces than in its usual setting of normal spaces. If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint closed sets, and $d$ is the metric, then $d(x,A)/(d(x,A)+d(x,B))$ is a continuous function of $x$, identically $0$ on $A$ and identically $1$ on $B$.  (I don't know whether a uniform structure would give you an easy proof.)

Comment: The function Andreas mentioned shows that ZF proves the result for metric spaces. ​ It follows from [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/73999/5810) that ZF does _not_ prove the corresponding result for uniform spaces. ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ (Also, just to make sure: ​ ​ ​ Is the "disjoint" in your comment referring to their _overall_ intersection? ​ In non-empty spaces, _pairwise_ intersections of such subsets are trivially always non-empty, so in non-empty spaces, the only way such collections can be _pairwise_ disjoint is if there is at most one such subset.) ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Thanks for the link, and my assertion was referencing pairwise disjointness, however I wasn't considering that the sets need be open.  I was thinking about the nonstandard analogues of rational and irrational numbers, which are obviously not open or closed under the interval topology/nonstandard metric $\xi$-topology. Thanks for catching the error!